# When updating angular version 7.2.0 to 8.0.0 getting error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Please guide me what's wrong here,I made changa angular version update but now I. Not able to run my project because of error.  Please click on link.[angular version change 7.2.0 to 8.0.0 getting document issues any every module.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJPcn.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried deleting your `node_modules` folder then reinstalling? Have you read Angular's upgrade guide to check for deprecations? https://update.angular.io/#7.2:8.0

Comment: Yes i did,new setup also.

Comment: I am following angular.io update steps.